# Ensuring recommender doesn't just pick top items

Tags: recommender-system

When building a hybrid recommender for products, how do you ensure that the model doesn't just recommender the most popular products all the time? Would throwing out X% (where X is high) of transactions involving this popular product be a good idea? With a hybrid model, could this most popular product just be left out of the data entirely?

Answer (score 1):

By hybrid recommender, I assume you mean a system that weights both a user's profile/behavior and item content. By its very nature, a hybrid recommender will use item content which is independent of popularity. Collaborative filtering recommends popular items among users with similar profile/behavior, which is not the same as overall popularity.

Comment: Hmmm, this isn't an answer to my question. You correctly point out that the meta-data parts of the model will move the model away from just recommending top items, but what if my model still does anyway, i.e. because some items are just *really* popular?